# how to add a product in cart from external php file in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, php

i've an external php file called addtocart.php who is located in my magento root folder. with this file i want to add a product to the cart. the product should have the following attributes:

sku name options price(!!) qty

EDIT: this is a screenshot of my magento folder structure: https://www.dropbox.com/s/vmli0973iflfski/Screenshot%202014-02-12%2009.44.39.png

this is my code: (only with qty and sku)

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');    
umask(0);
Mage::app('de');


$image = "uploads/52f7857f039b2.jpg";
// the ID of the product
$product_id  = 149;

$product     = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);



$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
$cart->init();
$params = array(
    'product' => $product_id,
    'qty' => 1,
    'options' => array(
        149 => array(
                'quote_path' => $image,
                'secret_key' => substr(md5(file_get_contents(Mage::getBaseDir() . $image)), 0, 20)),
    )
);

$cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$cart->save();


Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
```

it does not work! can anybody tell me how to do this? Thank you! :)

Comment: have you tried changing $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart'); in $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); ?

Comment: yes, it does not work... do you have any idea how add products to the cart from a external php file?

Comment: This will make no difference. In this context it will behave the same as `getModel`.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks pretty strait forward (and works locally with a sample configurable product).  My guess is that you have a mal-formed `$params` array for those custom options.

It expects something along the lines of this...

```
$params = array(
    'product' => 1,
    'qty' => 1,
    'options' => array(
        26 => "value",
        42 => "another value here",
        71 => "yav"
)
);
```

What kind of custom option type is it that requires the value to be an array?

Answer (score 2):

This might help:

```
// Mage init
require_once '../../app/Mage.php';   
umask(0);    
Mage::init('default');  
Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name' => 'frontend'));  

// Get customer session
$session = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session'); 

// Get cart instance
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
$cart->init();

// Add a product with custom options
$productInstance = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$param = array(
    'product' => $productInstance->getId(),
    'qty' => 1,
    'options' => array(
        234 => 'A value'  // Custom option with id: 234
    )
);
$request = new Varien_Object();
$request->setData($param);
$cart->addProduct($productInstance, $param);            

// update session
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

// save the cart
$cart->save();
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21867045/magento-1-8-add-product-to-cart-using-php

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at the require call:

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');
```

The screenshot indicates addtocart.php is in the produktkonfigurator folder, so I would expect it to be something like:

```
require_once('../app/Mage.php');
```

As the app folder is one level up from addtocart.php's current directory.